# How to center the title text in pie chart highchart?

Tags: highcharts, donut-chart

I am trying to do center align the title text of the pie chart Highchart. Was able to achieve that but on mouse hover, and mouse out the title data doesn't get updated. Anyone can help me with the same.
On MouseHOver trying to do the below mentioned code

```js
 point: {
            events: {
              mouseOver: function() {
                                                  let span = '<span style="color:${this.color}" class="dealer-title">${this.y}<br/> <span style="color:#33383e;}" class="text-truncate" title="${this.name}"><b> </b></span></span>';

                $('.customTitle')[0].innerHTML = span
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

fiddle attached:
https://jsfiddle.net/5sutmqv3/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable `useHTML` argument in the `text` method call:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        ...
        var text = rend.text("textTexttext", left, top, true).attr({
            'text-anchor': 'middle',
            align: 'center',
            'zIndex': 10
          }).addClass('customTitle').add();
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w5a2jpk7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. After setting useHTML= true tooltip started getting overlap with the inner text of the pie chart. Can I set Z-Index so that it always comes on top?

Comment: Hi @Rohit Mehrotra, You need to also enable `useHTML` option for a tooltip and set background-color for it in a formatter function. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f0uraL1m/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't include html tags in the title. If you remove the SPANs it'll display the values.

```
$('.customTitle')[0].innerHTML = this.y
```

Comment: But I need to show HTML. Is there any way to do that? My requirement is to display the name & total percentage share of that certain browser. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I could be wrong. All I know is I tried it using a simple span tag and no other attributes and it failed to display. I suppose an option would be to create your own element outside of highcharts and position that.